# How do I set Windows environment variables permanently?

Tags: windows, windows-7, environment-variables, development-environment, windows-7-x64

How do I set Windows environment variables permanently?

I see that the Windows environment variables are reset when you close the command window. I want to set them permanently, so that I don't have to repeat the task every time I use the [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface).

Comment: This must already have been a mega duplicate in 2013. What is the canonical question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on Computer, Advanced system settings, select Advanced tab and click Environment variables.

Note: once you modify the environment variables, you will have to restart your applications, including CLI.

Comment: For windows 8 users: Typing "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System" in the file explorer exposes the "Advance System Settings" link.

Comment: This may [depend on the version of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows/72341522#72341522). What version is it?

Answer (score 10):

This can also be achieved from a **command prompt**. The following example sets a variable at the user level:

```
SETX variable_name value
```

For machine level, elevation is required:

```
SETX variable_name value /m
```

Comment: If you use this for updating %PATH%, this will cut it down to 1024 chars and potentially delete every path behind that range. So take care when using.