# Find x(86)) folder

Tags: java

My laptop is 32bit I installed my jdk bundle i586.then I installed my j2me 2.5.2  when I try To run the program no emulator appear I know my jdk should be in c:\ program\x(86) folder but I can't find the folder. Can. You help?

Comment: If you can't find a folder on your computer, how can people who do not even have access to your computer help you find it?

Answer (score 1):

On a machine with 64-bit Windows, "`Program Files`" is for 64-bit programs, and "`Program Files (x86)`" is for 32-bit programs.

On a machine with 32-bit Windows, there is only one folder, named "`Program Files`", for 32-bit programs.

Note that the name "`Program Files`" should never be hardcoded, since it can be [localized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Files#Localization).

For more info, see Wikipedia: [Program Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Files).
See also: [Using %PROGRAMFILES(x86)% on Windows OS 32bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17688758/5221149)