# Nodemon isn't recognized

Tags: windows, node.js, nodemon

When I run nodemon on Windows 8 it isn't recognized as a command.

[When I do the steps in the accepted answer of this post it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975999/i-can%C2%B4t-install-nodemon-globally-nodemon-not-recognized)s - but I have to repeat the same thing *every time* I open the terminal. How do I fix this?

I want to run nodemon as if it was global without hassle.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

[I found the answer and it is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312348/how-do-i-set-windows-environment-variables-permanently)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set [Environment variables](https://superuser.com/a/284351/441351) to also point to npm installed packages.